# Angular app integrated with key cloak is redirecting to login page ONLY ON page refresh

Tags: keycloak, angular8, openid-connect, keycloak-angular

I have an Angular app, which is configured with key cloak Authentication. Once every 30minutes, the cookie/session set by key cloak gets expired . As per the default behavior, the app is redirecting to login page when the user refreshes the app manually.

1. But I wanted it some thing like whenever the token get expired , redirect the current session to key cloak login page. (this should happen automatically, i.e., even with out user manual refreshes the page.)
2. There is a keycloak API, that collects the user login-logout entries in it.
   "**http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms//events?dateFrom=2022-02-09&dateTo=2022-02-10&first=0&max=9999999&type=LOGIN&type=LOGIN_ERROR&type=LOGOUT&type=LOGOUT_ERROR**"
   when ever user is refreshing the Angular App on browser window, each of refresh action is considered as a login entries and this API response keep on increasing with log. How to prevent this and get the log only for Login & Logout entires.

Here is the configuration set in **app.init.ts**

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import {keycloakConfigs  } from  '../../assets/config/serverdetails.json';
export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
return () =>
    keycloak.init({
        config: {
            url:  keycloakConfigs.Url,
            realm: keycloakConfigs.Realm,
            clientId: keycloakConfigs.ClientId,
        },
        initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            checkLoginIframe: true,
            checkLoginIframeInterval: 25
        },
        loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true
    });
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this later?